# Regex alphanumeric on paragraph

Tags: regex, match

I am trying to create a regex that should only match the alphanumeric character having length of 11 in the paragraph as provided in the example. The problem is that it also selects the string containing alphabets only.

My regex and input data [can be seen here](https://regex101.com/r/3746Sr/2).

Sample text:

```
 RCLO                                          DD  12-10-15  IAD        RO N2905198759                                PTD 12-08-15  SWC          
 CRO N2905198759                               FCD 12-07-15  WOT 12-0
 MCN 999LDCMCWCG PROJECT 309097-2          VER  04    OCO TSR BSRNCA70M00 
 WORK DESCRIPTION AND NOTES:                          CCO TSR BSRNCA70M00 
MANUALLY 
 DIVERSER CIRCUITS SEE RPON, 9152 IRMK AAI DWGVILAZW02 IRMK ALCON  IDR INFORMATION U 
 PDATED ON THE DESIGN AT HFESILWL AND EGVGILEG
```

The pattern is

```
\b([A-Z0-9]{11})\b
```

In the above example it should not select "DESCRIPTION" and "INFORMATION"

Comment: Do you mean you do not want both `DESCRIPTION` and `99999999999`?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I am looking for

Comment: You could also use a negative lookahead: [`\b(?![A-Z]+\b|\d+\b)[A-Z\d]{11}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/kfxnyn/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{11}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YFCAJK/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])` - after 0+ uppercase ASCII letters, there must be 1 ASCII digit
- `(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])` - after 0+ ASCII digits, there must be 1 uppercase ASCII letter
- `[A-Z0-9]{11}` - 11 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `\b`  -  a trailing word boundary.